# How do I know which routes are handled by a controller in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am trying to write a script/program that given a controller file name, can programmatically determine which routes are served by this controller. This should work for inheritance use cases as well. For example:

```
class UserController < UserBaseController


end
```

```
class UserBaseController
  def update
    # changes made here
  end 
end
```

Running the script given the UserBaseController should return something like: PUT users/:id

How can I go about doing this? I tried using rails routes. However, the routes map to the child class and not the parent class which is where the change was actually made.

Thank you!

Comment: This is doable (kind of) but would be slow as hell. To do this you would first have to look up the constant based on the file name and then you woulld have to loop through every route in the application and see if any of the controllers contain the given constant in their ancestors chain.

Comment: If you want to do this you need to start by breaking the job down into reasonably scoped questions - eg How do I resolve a constant from a file name? How do I loop through the routes defined in a Rails app? How do I find the ancestors of a class? Come back to us once you have made an attempt at actually solving the question.